# PYMC Deterministic variable with parent as class attribute

Tags: python, python-2.7, pymc

I am trying to create a PYMC Deterministic variable that looks like the following.

```
@pymc.deterministic
def tau(s = sigma):
    return 1.0/(s**2)
```

However, in my case, the model parameters (PYMC Stochastic variables) are defined as class attributes. As a result, `sigma` is accessible only to class methods (through `self.sigma`). Trying to make this a class method like the following

```
@pymc.deterministic
def tau(self, s = None):
    sigma = self.sigma
    return 1.0/(sigma**2)
```

throws an error (obviously).

> ValueError: Deterministic tau: no parent provided for the following label: self

How can I create a PYMC Deterministic variable whose parent is an attribute of a class?

P.S. Not sure if it matters, but I am using PYMC 2.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19787928/passing-parameters-to-deterministic-variables-pymc) mildly related question, I was able to figure out a way to capture class attributes as parents to a PYMC Deterministic variable. The solution is to use PYMC's [Lambda](http://pymcmc.readthedocs.org/en/jss-gp/modelbuilding.html#creation-of-deterministic-variables) class which converts a Python `lambda` function into a Deterministic instance. This seems to be a rather clean way.

```
self.tau = pymc.Lambda('tau', lambda s = self.sigma: 1.0/(s**2))
```